# Lock gnome screen during a specified time period without a way to unlock it

Tags: gnome

I am using gnome in CentOS. What I want to achieve is to lock the computer completely during a  specified time span, say 23:00~7:00.

**Attempts**

1. I tried to create Python + Qt app, but it can be easily worked around by switching to another session and killing it.
2. There is a app called 'typing break' which is similar to what I want to do, but there is no way to enable it at time point A and disable it at time point B.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the screensaver with `gnome-screensaver-command`

```
$ gnome-screensaver-command --help
Usage:
  gnome-screensaver-command [OPTION…]

Help Options:
  -h, --help           Show help options

Application Options:
  --exit               Causes the screensaver to exit gracefully
  -q, --query          Query the state of the screensaver
  -t, --time           Query the length of time the screensaver has been active
  -l, --lock           Tells the running screensaver process to lock the screen immediately
  -a, --activate       Turn the screensaver on (blank the screen)
  -d, --deactivate     If the screensaver is active then deactivate it (un-blank the screen)
  -V, --version        Version of this application
```

In your case, a cronjob might be sufficient. I.e.

```
0 23 * * * DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command --lock
0  7 * * * DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command --deactivate
```